# Populate the JTable using JComboBox instead of a JButton

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am just a beginner in Java and I would be glad if you could help me, I have here a JTable which is populated using JButton with data from the database. I have 3 tables named **students**, **teachers**, & **directors**.
Everything is working fine in viewing those fields in the JTable using the 3 JButtons(one for each table). But everytime I clicked to another JButton, the JTable is not cleared but instead adding the data to the existing information on the JTable.

Now, what I want to do is to replace the 3 JButtons into a JComboBox wherein the options to select are the table names and displaying their contents in the JTable. I really don't have any idea on how to do this.
I hope you can help me with this and would really appreciate any inputs.

Thanks

Below are the codes I used. I also included some captions.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class tests extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form tests
 */
public tests() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    dataTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
    students = new javax.swing.JButton();
    teachers = new javax.swing.JButton();
    directors = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    dataTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID", "Name", "Surname", "Age"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(dataTable);

    students.setText("Students");
    students.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            studentsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    teachers.setText("Teachers");
    teachers.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            teachersActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    directors.setText("Directors");
    directors.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            directorsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(students)
            .addGap(57, 57, 57)
            .addComponent(teachers)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 66, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(directors)
            .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(students)
                .addComponent(teachers)
                .addComponent(directors))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 274, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void studentsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from students";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void teachersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from teachers";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void directorsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from directors";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new tests().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTable dataTable;
private javax.swing.JButton directors;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton students;
private javax.swing.JButton teachers;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

See the caption [here.](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=eb81d7d0042dfe6b&resid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!163&parid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!158&authkey=!AKnm0e6UCN52xWs)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But everytime I clicked to another JButton, the JTable is not cleared but instead adding the data to the existing information on the JTable.` -- this shouldn't surprise you since the program is only doing what you tell it to do. Your button's ActionListener only adds rows the table model. I'm sure you can figure out that to replace data, first you have to remove the old data or replace the model with a new one, right? The DefaultTableModel API has methods that you can use for this.

Comment: Also, I don't see your code for your attempt to do what you want with a JComboBox. If you forgot to post the code, please edit your question and post it, otherwise we'll have no idea what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Sir, please advise, I'm completely lost on this. I'm just new to Java so please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how HFOE could have helped you better.  You can help yoruself though, by answering their questions & following their suggestions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sir, I've already done the ComboBox part wherein it will display on the JTable. My problem is how to make the JTable display only the content of the database and not appending on the existing data on the JTable. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a project you are working on for a school?  For a college?  What are you trying to create, or what data management problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: @Thorn: yes Sir, this is a project at our school. My problem is when I select an option from the JComboBox, it will display the information in the JTable however when I select to another option, the information is appended on the existing data in the JTable. How can I display only the information of a certain database to the JTable? See this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=eb81d7d0042dfe6b&resid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!165&parid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!158&authkey=!AP4pPOBcvfh0XLU) if you are confused. Sorry for the bad english. 

Thanks a lot Sir!

Comment: @Karl I build software for schools and I'm interested in seeing what other people are doing.  I looked at your link; your project is interesting - it looks like you are building some data management system.  Please email me: support@proctinator.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add JComboBox instead of JButtons like this,

```
String[] items = {"students", "teachers", "directors"};
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(items);
cb.setEditable(true);
```

Add Listener class to combobox like this,

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    //System.out.println("Selected: " + cb.getSelectedItem());
     if(cb.getSelectedItem() == "student"){

       //Perform the action for student

     } 

      //Repeat this for all items

  }
};
cb.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

This will do what you are expecting....

Comment: `private void comBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {           
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();  
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
            Connection connect = (Connection)                      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
                Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);`

--> I still can't retrieve data from my database using the JComboBox
what do you think is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested actionListener is working for your combobox change event?

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. Actually, not so sure about it.
What do you think is missing?

`    private void comBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        
            if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Students"){
             JComboBox comBox = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
             String select = (String)comBox.getSelectedItem();       
            }`

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you are little bit confused just add, if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "students") { //add action code what you have performed for student button } like that, else if(comBox.getSelectedItem() == "teachers"){ // add action code respect to teacher button}

Comment: It **WORKS!!!**

Thank you mery much Mr. Vinesh. Finally I got it! I know it's just very simple but it means a lot for a beginner like me.
But everytime I select to another Database it just adds to the existing table. What should I do so that it only displays its own database?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use model.removeRow() in a loop to remove rows, before adding rows.

Comment: What loop? Where should I put it? Please advise. Really need help.
Thanks!

Comment: for( int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){ model.removeRow(i); }  use it before model.addRow()

Comment: Thanks for that Sir, but that's not what I want to do. Though it work but what I mean is when I select to a database, it will display all its content while when selecting to another, it also dislay its own content. How will I do this?

I really appreciate your effort Sir. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sir, I would just like to ask if there is a way where the Menu that will be on the JComboBox are the name of the database so that there is no need for me to add an **if else** for every database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an ActionListener for your JCombobox. In the actionListener, change the data in the table based on the value returned by the getSelectedItem().

Try writing it and post your code if you need more help

Comment: I don't really understnand what you mean by 'add' ActionListener since I'm just new to it. Maybe if you can give a sample I can understand it. Thank you very much.

Comment: what I mean by 'add' is said by Vinesh in his post.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that Sir. I've already solved the issue regarding the JComboBox, my problem now is how to display only the data of a certain database when I select from the JComboBox and doesn't append on the existing data on the JTable. Please see the captions [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=eb81d7d0042dfe6b&resid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!165&parid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!158&authkey=!AP4pPOBcvfh0XLU) if you are confused. 

Thanks a lot!